# Transforming a String to a File using View Transformer

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.2

I'm currently using a crud application to create a blog style site.

The blog object requires an upload of a file, which I store in the database as a string.  However, when I try to edit an existing Blog, I get this error.

```
The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File, but is a(n) string. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view transformer that transforms a(n) string to an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File.
```

I'm trying to figure out how to do this.  A google search did point me to the page where view transformers a re explained.  But the example there shows how to transform a string to an Entity (and Issue).  However, I'm not sure if this is exactly the way I should handle this, since the object I am trying to transform a string into is a class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File.  I was just wondering of anyone know how I could go about doing this.  I'm under the impression that I would have to get a actual file type of the class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File and that is what I am stumped on.  How does one do this?

Answer (score 3):

Ok.  so it did take me a while to figure this out, but it was my first time.  Essentially what I did was use the CallBackTranformer() function in the BlogType.php class and transformed the object, in this case the File to a null object when rendering it in the form, and then just returned it in the other direction.

Here is the code, in case anyone wants to see it.

```
$builder->get('imageUrl')->addModelTransformer(new CallBackTransformer(
        function($imageUrl) {
            return null;
        },
        function($imageUrl) {
            return $imageUrl;
        }
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your updateAction or editAction in the begining of method add somethink like this:

```
public function updateAction(Request $request ,$posts) { 

     $posts->setFile( 
            new File($this->getParameter('images_directory').'/'.$posts->getFile()
     ));
```

Just like in the symfony site:
https://symfony.com/doc/3.2/controller/upload_file.html

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
// ...

$product->setBrochure(
    new File($this->getParameter('brochures_directory').'/'.$product->getBrochure())
);
```